# Print all lines in datafile without if condition

Tags: python

```
file = open("datafile1.txt", "rU")
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    print line
    for element in line:
         line = 2
```

Here is what i have so far, and the output looks like from a simple datafile i created:

```
blind
element
baker
enjoy
```

Which corresponds to what is entered into the datafile1 that i want to read.
I am trying to read this datafile1 and print all the lines, but the first one without a if condition.  I was thinking of slicing [2:] in the for loop, but i can't figure out how to just print the  element,baker, and enjoy "without print the first line which is blind".

Can you please give me some suggestion how to read and print just those characters without using if statement.  The only way i know of would be using a Try and except to replace the if statement and read only the last three lines of the file.   Any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Nevermind I didn't notice you're using python2

Comment: nah its some concepts I'm trying to understand that i was stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

File objects work like iterators, so you can `next()` them to consume one element (one line) before actually iterating over them.

```
file = open("datafile1.txt", "rU")
next(file, None)
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    print line
```

For a small file you could also read it into a list and then use the slice operator:

```
with open("datafile1.txt", "rU") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # or lines = [l.strip() for l in f]
for line in lines[1:]:
    print line
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the "with" keyword or the "next" actually never studied them. Can explain what they do a little thanks.

Comment: The [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) simply ensures the file is closed after leaving the block. It saves you from writing `f.close()` when you are done. [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) returns the next element from an iterator - on a newly opened file it's the first line. The second argument `None` is used so it never raises `StopIteration` if there is no next element (in an empty file).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and fast reply i appreciated it!  How would i write that code if i didn't want to use "with" or "next"

Answer (score 2):

You cold use somthing like this:

```
with open("datafile1.txt") as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
       #do something awesome
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [linecache.getline(filename, lineno)](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html#linecache.getline)